# How to check if a user's device supports and authorizes iBeacon usage and has bluetooth powered on?

Tags: ios, ios7, cllocationmanager, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

There are a lot of steps for checking if a user's device can monitor iBeacons and steps to suggest what the user can do to enable iBeacon monitoring. I remember seeing some gists for circular region monitoring (geofences). Is there something similar for iBeacons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - `CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn` and `isRangingAvailable`

`isRangingAvailable` returns a Boolean indicating whether the device supports ranging of BlueTooth beacons. See [CLLocationManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CLLocationManager/isMonitoringAvailableForClass%3a).

When `CBCentralManagerState` is `CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn`, it indicates BlueTooth is ready and not powered off. See [CBCentralManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/translated_content/CBCentralManager.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn).

Answer (score 0):

**isMonitoringAvailableForClass** is the method that can be used for checking whether device can monitor or not.

**CBPeripheralManagerStateUnsupported** is the state that comes when ibeacon device is not supported for transmissiuon in peripheralManagerDidUpdateState method.

Also **isRangingAvail** method can be used for ranging purpose.